# how to add images from URL to ListBox

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

i want to load images from URL list in ListBox items, this my code to retrieve the URLs

```
var
 LJSONArray : TJSONArray;
 LEntity: TBackendEntityValue;
 I : integer;
begin
 try
  LJSONArray := TJSONArray.Create;
  BackendStorage1.Storage.QueryObjects('list', [], LJSONArray);
   for I := 0 to LJSONArray.Count-1 do
    begin
     ListBox4.Items.Add (LJSonArray.Items[I].GetValue<string>('Pictures'));
    end;
  finally
  LJSONArray.Free;
 end;
 end;
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 LBItem    : TListBoxItem;
 i: integer;
 HTTP : TIdHttp;
 Stream : TMemoryStream;
begin
 HTTP := TIdHttp.Create(nil);
try
 for i := 0 to ListBox1.Items.Count-1 do
  begin
   LBItem := TListBoxItem.Create(nil);
   LBItem.Parent := ListBox2;
   LBItem.Height := 100;
   Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
   HTTP.Get(ListBox1.Items.Strings[i], Stream);
   LBItem.ItemData.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(Stream);

  end;
 finally
  Stream.Free;
  HTTP.Free;
end;
end;
```

i tried loading the pictures in another ListBox, however, there are items added but without pictures !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `TIdHTTP.Get()` downloads the image to your `TMemoryStream`, you need to seek the stream to Position 0 before you do anything with it, like loading it into your `Bitmap`.  And add a `try..except` block to handle download errors.

Also, you should be using a second `try..finally` block for freeing the `TMemoryStream`.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 LBItem    : TListBoxItem;
 i: integer;
 HTTP : TIdHttp;
 Stream : TMemoryStream;
begin
 HTTP := TIdHttp.Create(nil);
try
 for i := 0 to ListBox1.Items.Count-1 do
  begin
   LBItem := TListBoxItem.Create(nil);
   LBItem.Parent := ListBox2;
   LBItem.Height := 100;
   Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
   try
     try
       HTTP.Get(ListBox1.Items.Strings[i], Stream);
       Stream.Position := 0; // <-- add this
       LBItem.ItemData.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(Stream);
     except
       // do something else
     end;
   finally
     Stream.Free;
   end;
  end;
 finally
  HTTP.Free;
 end;
end;
```

Comment: still no images, just empty items!,

Comment: You are not assigning any text to the list items. How are you displaying their bitmaps? How have you configured the ListBox? Have you debugged the code to make sure the bitmaps are not empty?

Comment: i assigned `LBItem.Text := 'Test';`  and its added to ListBox2 items but without Pictures!, i tried `LBItem.ItemData.Bitmap.SaveToFile('C:/1.jpg');` and the picture saved in `C:/` !, i dont understand why its not showing in ListBox2 items 1

Comment: You did not answer my question. How exactly do you have the ListBox configured? I don't use FireMonkey myself, so I'm not sure if there are extra steps needed to tell it how to display the `ItemData.Bitmap`. For instance, does your ListBox's layout/style define a place to show an image, and is it bound to the `ItemData.Bitmap`?

Comment: honestly im not sure, but there is Images property `TCustomImageList` in the ListBox, however, i looked to the CustomListbox sample from embarcadero, they are using it like this `Item.ItemData.Bitmap := Image1.Bitmap`

Comment: i manged to get it done, you need to link the ListBox to a StyleBook , just have a look at  CustomListbox sample, Many thanks mate.